# How to fix list.contains(object) not returning the good boolean variable

Tags: java, list, arraylist, random, contains

I am trying to make a list with some array, generated random, within a range and with a fixed size. The problem is, when I want to see if an array is already in the list (list.contains(array)) it's not returning the good boolean variable. This is how this code looks like, and I have no idea from where's the problem:

```
List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<int[]>();
int[] v = new int[n];
int n = 2, val_max = 3;

while (list.size() != max) {
  v = getRandomArray(n, 1, val_max);
  if (list.contains(v) == false)
    list.add(v);
}
```

I expect the output for that to be `{ {1, 2} {2, 1} {1, 3} {3, 1} {2, 3} {3, 2} }` but the output keeps changing... It always doubles one or two of the above values which is what made me think that the problem must be from the contains function.

Answer (score 1):

`List.contains` uses `Object.equals` to check for equality, but arrays use reference equality, not content equality.  So `.contains` will always return false.

Unfortunately, for arrays specifically, there really are only two options:

- Rewrite the logic of `contains` yourself, using `Arrays.equals`.
- Wrap the arrays in a new object of your own creation and write its equality methods appropriately.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
      if (Arrays.equals(list.get(i), v) == true)
       return true;
     }
     return false;
    I've tried this within a function, contains_list, but still it doesn't work

Comment: A third option: use a `TreeSet` with an explicit comparator which compares `int[]`s lexicographically. (Of course, that wouldn't preserve insertion order).

Comment: Yet another option:  wrap each array in an [IntBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/IntBuffer.html).  That class does have an `equals` method based on the values of the array elements.